# how to pass arguments(if the input is taken by user) to functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, attributeerror

i am a beginner to Python language and i am facing a problem in passing  arguments(if the input is taken by user) to functions in **python**.
The error which i am getting is **AttributeError: 'Complexno' object has no attribute 'a'**

here is my code: 
P.S. Correct me if i am wrong somewhere (please help i m stuck  )

```
 class Complexno:
     def add(self,a,c ,b,d):
         sum1=self.a+self.c
         sum2=self.b+self.d
         print(sum1+" + "+sum2)

    def sub(self,a,c,b,d):
        sub1=self.a-self.c
        sub2=self.b-self.d
        print(sub1+" - "+sub2)
    def mul(self,a,b,c,d):
        mul1=self.a*self.c
        mul2=self.b*self.c
        print(mul1+" * "+mul2)

    def div(self,a,b,c,d):
        div1=self.a/self.c
        div2=self.b/self.d
        print(div1+" / "+div2)



a=float(input("Enter the real part of first no"))
b=float(input("Enter the  imaginary part of first no"))
c=float(input("Enter the real part of second no"))
d=float(input("Enter the imaginary part of second no"))

ob1=Complexno()
ob1.add(a,b,c,d)
ob1.sub(a,b,c,d)
ob1.div(a,b,c,d)
ob1.mul(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: You're calling the functions by different args and expecting different in the method itself. Do `ob1.add(a, c, b, d)` and it'll be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing a class variable that you have not set.

You will not have this problem anymore if you remove the `self` references within the methods.

```
class Complexno:
    def add(self,a,c ,b,d):
        sum1= a + c
        sum2= b + d
        print(sum1+" + "+sum2)

   def sub(self,a,c,b,d):
       sub1= a - c
       sub2= b - d
       print(sub1+" - "+sub2)

   def mul(self,a,b,c,d):
       mul1= a * c
       mul2= b * c
       print(mul1+" * "+mul2)

   def div(self,a,b,c,d):
       div1= a / c
       div2= b / d
       print(div1+" / "+div2)
```

A better solution might be to create a complex number class, initializing it with the real and imaginary parts and then overload the operations you care about to return another complex number.

```
class Complexno:
    def __inti__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.a = real
        self.b = imaginary

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}+{}i".format(self.a, self.b)

    def __add__(self, other):
        real = self.a + other.a
        imaginary = self.b + other.b
        return Complexno(real, imaginary)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        real = self.a - other.a
        imaginary = self.b - other.b
        return Complexno(real, imaginary)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        real = self.a * other.a
        imaginary = self.b * other.b
        return Complexno(real, imaginary)

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        real = self.a // other.a
        imaginary = self.b // other.b
        return Complexno(real, imaginary)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        real = self.a / other.a
        imaginary = self.b / other.b
        return Complexno(real, imaginary)
```

But if you are creating your own class, you will probably want to implement even more methods than this.

See [this page](http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-readable005.html) for an example of methods to add, however, it looks like that site is written for 2.7 because they use `__div__` instead of the two division methods needed for 3.x.

Using this class, you can then perform the operations like this:

```
a = float(input("Enter the real part of first no"))
b = float(input("Enter the  imaginary part of first no"))
c = float(input("Enter the real part of second no"))
d = float(input("Enter the imaginary part of second no"))

num1 = Complexno(a, b)
num2 = Complexno(c, d)

print(num1 + num2)
print(num1 - num2)
print(num1 * num2)
print(num1 / num2)
```